# Zephyr and amazon web services failing at mqtt_input

Tags: c, mqtt, zephyr-rtos

I am trying to use MQTT library to connect to Amazon IOT Service

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Intel Corporation
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

#include <logging/log.h>
LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(aws_mqtt, LOG_LEVEL_DBG);

#include <zephyr.h>
#include <net/socket.h>
#include <net/mqtt.h>
#include <net/net_config.h>
#include <net/net_event.h>
#include <net/sntp.h>

#include <sys/printk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "dhcp.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "globalsign.inc"

/* The mqtt client struct */
static struct mqtt_client client_ctx;
s64_t time_base;
/* MQTT Broker details. */
static struct sockaddr_storage broker;

#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKS)
static struct sockaddr socks5_proxy;
#endif
static struct pollfd fds[1];
static int nfds;

#define APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE    128

static sec_tag_t m_sec_tags[] = {
#if defined(MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C) || defined(CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_OFFLOAD)
    APP_CA_CERT_TAG,
#endif
#if defined(MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE__SOME__PSK_ENABLED)
    APP_PSK_TAG,
#endif
};
#define APP_CA_CERT_TAG 1
#define APP_PSK_TAG 2

/* Buffers for MQTT client. */
static u8_t rx_buffer[APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE];
static u8_t tx_buffer[APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE];
static bool connected;

#define MQTT_CLIENTID           "zephyr_publisher"

struct zsock_addrinfo *haddr;

time_t my_k_time(time_t *ptr)
{
    s64_t stamp;
    time_t now;

    stamp = k_uptime_get();
    now = (time_t)((stamp + time_base) / 1000);

    if (ptr) {
        *ptr = now;
    }

    return now;
}

static void broker_init(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in *broker4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)&broker;

    broker4->sin_family = AF_INET;
    broker4->sin_port = htons(8883);

    net_ipaddr_copy(&broker4->sin_addr,
            &net_sin(haddr->ai_addr)->sin_addr);

#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKS)
    struct sockaddr_in *proxy4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)&socks5_proxy;

    proxy4->sin_family = AF_INET;
    proxy4->sin_port = htons(1081);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "agwgaprlb6xdl-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", &proxy4->sin_addr);
#endif
}

void mqtt_evt_handler(struct mqtt_client *const client,
        const struct mqtt_evt *evt)
{
    int err;

    switch (evt->type) {
        case MQTT_EVT_CONNACK:
            if (evt->result != 0) {
                LOG_ERR("MQTT connect failed %d", evt->result);
                break;
            }

            connected = true;
            LOG_INF("MQTT client connected!");

            break;

        case MQTT_EVT_DISCONNECT:
            LOG_INF("MQTT client disconnected %d", evt->result);

            connected = false;
            //clear_fds();

            break;

        case MQTT_EVT_PUBACK:
            if (evt->result != 0) {
                LOG_ERR("MQTT PUBACK error %d", evt->result);
                break;
            }

            LOG_INF("PUBACK packet id: %u", evt->param.puback.message_id);

            break;

        case MQTT_EVT_PUBREC:
            if (evt->result != 0) {
                LOG_ERR("MQTT PUBREC error %d", evt->result);
                break;
            }

            LOG_INF("PUBREC packet id: %u", evt->param.pubrec.message_id);

            const struct mqtt_pubrel_param rel_param = {
                .message_id = evt->param.pubrec.message_id
            };
            err = mqtt_publish_qos2_release(client, &rel_param);
            if (err != 0) {
                LOG_ERR("Failed to send MQTT PUBREL: %d", err);
            }

            break;

        case MQTT_EVT_PUBCOMP:
            if (evt->result != 0) {
                LOG_ERR("MQTT PUBCOMP error %d", evt->result);
                break;
            }

            LOG_INF("PUBCOMP packet id: %u",
                    evt->param.pubcomp.message_id);

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}


static void client_init(struct mqtt_client *client)
{
        static struct mqtt_utf8 password;
        static struct mqtt_utf8 username;

    mqtt_client_init(client);
    broker_init();


    password.utf8 = (u8_t *)CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_PASSWORD;
    password.size = strlen(CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_PASSWORD);

    client->password = &password;

    username.utf8 = (u8_t *)CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_USERNAME;
    username.size = strlen(CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_USERNAME);

    client->user_name = &username;


    /* MQTT client configuration */
    client->broker = &broker;
    client->evt_cb = mqtt_evt_handler;
    client->client_id.utf8 = (u8_t *)MQTT_CLIENTID;
    client->client_id.size = strlen(MQTT_CLIENTID);
    client->password = NULL;
    client->user_name = NULL;
    client->protocol_version = MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1;

    /* MQTT buffers configuration */
    client->rx_buf = rx_buffer;
    client->rx_buf_size = sizeof(rx_buffer);
    client->tx_buf = tx_buffer;
    client->tx_buf_size = sizeof(tx_buffer);

    client->transport.type = MQTT_TRANSPORT_SECURE;

    struct mqtt_sec_config *tls_config = &client->transport.tls.config;

    tls_config->peer_verify = TLS_PEER_VERIFY_REQUIRED;
    tls_config->cipher_list = NULL;
    tls_config->sec_tag_list = m_sec_tags;
    tls_config->sec_tag_count = ARRAY_SIZE(m_sec_tags);
    tls_config->hostname = NULL;
    client->transport.type = MQTT_TRANSPORT_NON_SECURE;
#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKS)
    mqtt_client_set_proxy(client, &socks5_proxy,
            socks5_proxy.sa_family == AF_INET ?
            sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) :
            sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
#endif


}
#define RC_STR(rc) ((rc) == 0 ? "OK" : "ERROR")
#define PRINT_RESULT(func, rc) \
    LOG_INF("%s: %d <%s>", (func), rc, RC_STR(rc))
static void prepare_fds(struct mqtt_client *client)
{
    if (client->transport.type == MQTT_TRANSPORT_NON_SECURE) {
        fds[0].fd = client->transport.tcp.sock;
    }
#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS)
    else if (client->transport.type == MQTT_TRANSPORT_SECURE) {
        fds[0].fd = client->transport.tls.sock;
    }
#endif

    fds[0].events = ZSOCK_POLLIN;
    nfds = 1;
}
static void clear_fds(void)
{
    nfds = 0;
}

static void wait(int timeout)
{
    if (nfds > 0) {
        if (poll(fds, nfds, timeout) < 0) {
            LOG_ERR("poll error: %d", errno);
        }
    }
}



static int try_to_connect(struct mqtt_client *client)
{
    u8_t retries = 3U;
    int rc;

    LOG_DBG("attempting to connect...");

    client_init(client);
    rc = mqtt_connect(client);
    if (rc != 0) {
        PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_connect", rc);
        k_sleep(500);
    } else {

        prepare_fds(client);

        wait(500);
        mqtt_input(client);
        if (!connected) {
            LOG_INF("Aborting connection\n");
            mqtt_abort(client);
        }

    }
    if (connected) {
        return 0;
    }

    return -EINVAL;

}


void mqtt_startup(char *hostname, int port)
{
    struct mqtt_client *client = &client_ctx;
    int retries = 5;
    int err, cnt;   
    static struct zsock_addrinfo hints;
    int res = 0;
    int rc;


    mbedtls_platform_set_time(my_k_time);

    err = tls_credential_add(1, TLS_CREDENTIAL_CA_CERTIFICATE,
            globalsign_certificate,
            sizeof(globalsign_certificate));
    if (err < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to register public certificate: %d", err);
    }
    LOG_DBG("tls credential added\n");

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    cnt = 0;
    while ((err = getaddrinfo("agwgaprlb6xdl-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "8883", &hints,
                    &haddr)) && cnt < 3) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to get address for broker, retrying");
        cnt++;
    }
    if (err != 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to get address for broker, error %d",
                res);
        return;
    }
    LOG_INF("DNS resolved for agwgaprlb6xdl-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8833");
    try_to_connect(client);
    PRINT_RESULT("try_to_connect", rc);




}

static void show_addrinfo(struct addrinfo *addr)
{
    char hr_addr[NET_IPV6_ADDR_LEN];
    void *a;

top:
    LOG_DBG("  flags   : %d", addr->ai_flags);
    LOG_DBG("  family  : %d", addr->ai_family);
    LOG_DBG("  socktype: %d", addr->ai_socktype);
    LOG_DBG("  protocol: %d", addr->ai_protocol);
    LOG_DBG("  addrlen : %d", (int)addr->ai_addrlen);

    /* Assume two words. */
    LOG_DBG("   addr[0]: 0x%lx", ((uint32_t *)addr->ai_addr)[0]);
    LOG_DBG("   addr[1]: 0x%lx", ((uint32_t *)addr->ai_addr)[1]);

    if (addr->ai_next != 0) {
        addr = addr->ai_next;
        goto top;
    }

    a = &net_sin(addr->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
    LOG_INF("  Got %s",
            log_strdup(net_addr_ntop(addr->ai_family, a,
                    hr_addr, sizeof(hr_addr))));

}

void do_sntp(struct addrinfo *addr)
{
    struct sntp_ctx ctx;
    int rc;
    s64_t stamp;
    struct sntp_time sntp_time;
    char time_str[sizeof("1970-01-01T00:00:00")];

    LOG_INF("Sending NTP request for current time:");

    /* Initialize sntp */
    rc = sntp_init(&ctx, addr->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (rc < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to init sntp context: %d", rc);
        return;
    }
    rc = sntp_query(&ctx, K_FOREVER, &sntp_time);
    if (rc == 0) {
        stamp = k_uptime_get();
        time_base = sntp_time.seconds * MSEC_PER_SEC - stamp;

        /* Convert time to make sure. */
        time_t now = sntp_time.seconds;
        struct tm now_tm;

        gmtime_r(&now, &now_tm);
        strftime(time_str, sizeof(time_str), "%FT%T", &now_tm);
        LOG_INF("  Acquired time: %s", log_strdup(time_str));

    } else {
        LOG_ERR("  Failed to acquire SNTP, code %d\n", rc);
    }

    sntp_close(&ctx);
}


void main(void)
{
    static struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *haddr;
    int res;
    int cnt = 0;


    app_dhcpv4_startup();

    LOG_INF("Should have DHCPv4 lease at this point.");
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    //while ((res = getaddrinfo("console.aws.amazon.com", "80", &hints,
    while ((res = getaddrinfo("time.google.com", "123", &hints,
                    &haddr)) && cnt < 3) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to get address for NTP server, retrying");
        cnt++;
    }

    if (res != 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to get address of NTP server, exiting %d", res);
        return;
    }


    LOG_INF("DNS resolved for console.aws.amazon.com:80");
    show_addrinfo(haddr);
    do_sntp(haddr);
    mqtt_startup("agwgaprlb6xdl-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", 8883);    

}
```

Following are the logs:

```
[00:00:07.193,000] <dbg> net_mqtt_enc.pack_uint8: (0x20401bac): >> val:10 cur:0x20401d64, end:0x20401de1
[00:00:07.205,000] <dbg> net_mqtt_enc.packet_length_encode: (0x20401bac): >> length:0x0000001c cur:0x20401d65, end:0x20401de1
[00:00:07.219,000] <dbg> net_mqtt.client_connect: (0x20401bac): Connect completed
[00:00:07.684,000] <dbg> net_mqtt.mqtt_input: (0x20401bac): state:0x00000002
[00:00:07.693,000] <dbg> net_mqtt_rx.mqtt_read_message_chunk: (0x20401bac): [CID 0x20400254]: Connection closed.
[00:00:07.706,000] <dbg> net_mqtt_sock_tcp.mqtt_client_tcp_disconnect: (0x20401bac): Closing socket 0
[00:00:07.718,000] <err> aws_mqtt: MQTT connect failed -111
[00:00:07.726,000] <inf> aws_mqtt: Aborting connection

[00:00:07.734,000] <inf> aws_mqtt: try_to_connect: 0 <OK>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This issue number indicates the connection was refused by the host.

It usually happens when using the wrong TLS certs or user login info, I would double check my certs or pass/username.

It seems in your case the issue is because of here, look you're overwriting your login info with null.

```
    password.utf8 = (u8_t *)CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_PASSWORD;
    password.size = strlen(CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_PASSWORD);

    client->password = &password;

    username.utf8 = (u8_t *)CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_USERNAME;
    username.size = strlen(CONFIG_SAMPLE_CLOUD_AWS_USERNAME);

    client->user_name = &username;
.
.
.
    /* MQTT client configuration */
    client->broker = &broker;
    client->evt_cb = mqtt_evt_handler;
    client->client_id.utf8 = (u8_t *)MQTT_CLIENTID;
    client->client_id.size = strlen(MQTT_CLIENTID);
    client->password = NULL;
    client->user_name = NULL;
    client->protocol_version = MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1;
.
.
```